# How to allow command for user www-data?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, webserver

I try to execute the following PHP command to get the IP-adress from eth0.

```
$ip = trim(shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep -i 'inet Adresse:' | tr ':' ' ' | awk '{ print $3 }'"));
```

But i get nothing back. If i execute the exact same command via ssh then i get the IP, so the command should work.

I opened `visudo` and added these lines and restarted apache2 after it

```
www-data        ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
www-data        ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/grep
www-data        ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/awk
www-data        ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tr
```

But i still get nothing back

Comment: Thanks for -1 without letting me know what i did wrong, very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Your grep pattern doesn't seem to match the output of `ifconfig` and therefore `grep` is producing no output, try:

```
$ip = trim(shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep -i 'inet Adresse:' | awk '{ print $2 }'"));
```

Comment: Now i get nothing back if i execute your command directly in the terminal, it is because my OS is set to german and if i execute `ifconfig` then i get `inet Adresse:` not `inet addr:`

Comment: @EdwardBlack ok, can you run the command `/sbin/ifconfig` direct on the machine you want the ipaddress of and then post the output into your question (blank out your ip address etc)

Comment: ok, but where is the best place to paste the output in? I guess it is not helpful if i post it into the comments? I post it here: http://www.pasteall.org/68935/php

Comment: @EdwardBlack it would be best to update your question with the data as it helps to answer your question. but thats cool. I've updated my answer. can you try the new command now?

Comment: Now i get `encap` as output

Comment: @EdwardBlack ok, yeah awk needs to be updated, can you just keep increasing the `$x` awk column, so try `awk '{ print $4 }'` , then `awk '{ print $5 }'` keep increasing until you get to the ipaddress.

Comment: This does not work, i only get output till $12

Comment: @EdwardBlack I've updated my answer,  I think `tr` was causing issues, can you try my new command?

Comment: Now i get the mac adress

Comment: oh sorry , I was matching the wrong line! give me a sec

Comment: @EdwardBlack sorry I can't see whats wrong, your original command should actually work. I have updated my command to a hacky fallback. It should give your your IP address but it will probably look like `Adresse:172.25.8.21` - if this works then maybe you could clean it up from inside PHP?

Comment: The command is not the problem, mine works well. The only problem is that it does not work from PHP with shell_exec, i get no output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is because `shell_exec` always gets an english output, even if the OS is set to german, if you execute `shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig")` then you will always get e.g. `inet addr` instead of `inet Adresse` in the output.

I also forgot to change the user and group of my file to `www-data` with `chown`and to allow execution of the script with `chmod`, i don't know if this is necessary though.

Comment: *Offtop*. @Black, can you tell me, did [**my comment**](https://superuser.com/questions/1274825#comment2240585_1274825) help you? Thanks.