# uTorrent starting up automatically

Tags: windows-10, boot, bittorrent, utorrent

I installed uTorrent couple of months ago and while installing I unchecked the box that says "Start uTorrent with Windows" and it worked that way until few days ago when I turn on the PC uTorrent is already up and running, it seems like it doesn't even need time to start. I thought some settings got messed up and went to `Task Manager->Start Up` but uTorrent was't there. What can I do to stop it from doing that? Running on Win 10, latest version of uTorrent - 3.5.0 build 44294

Comment: Uninstall uTorrent.

Comment: Perhaps my answer [Want to delay startup of program but can't find it in Task Scheduler](//superuser.com/a/1047629) will help you :)

Comment: Consider using an opensourced torrent program that doesn't track your behavior. Like: deluge-torrent, or qbittorrent

Comment: @Black, try [**this `.reg` file**](https://www.pastery.net/nbnkjn/); it helps for my Windows 10. Also, you can see [**my personal full `.reg` file**](https://www.pastery.net/hkykvm/) for disabling auto starting of many programs and services. You can get more information, follow the links in the file. Thanks.

Comment: Try in utorrent preferences to untick the check-boxes to close to tray or minimize and then close it. Verify in Task Manager that utorrent.exe has really stopped.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, I created a new entry in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]` ->  `uTorrent` with value `-` like you suggested, and it works! It does not start automatically anymore :) Please make an answer and you will receive the bounty.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, Post your answer so I can reward you the bounty.

Comment: @Black Can you confirm that works for more than just a few reboots?

Comment: @Elmo, yes it works even after multiple reboots.

Comment: I'm not able to post _answer_, but what helped me was removing **helper** from `C:\Users\<your-user>\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\helper`

Comment: @brian It worked. What was the purpose of this helper application? . I hope it does interfere with uTorrent working. I had no idea that it would be so difficult to disable uTorrent(Windows 10).

Comment: @Aman It's like an updater

Comment: @brain how did you know this? . That helper application was responsible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Verify that the startup option is disabled in uTorrent options.
2. Check if you have a uTorrent shortcuts under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\`, if so - remove it.

   - When windows start, it will [run](https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/) each of the files in that directory.

Comment: Tried everything you mentioned, it still starts with windows...

Comment: I think that path is outdated for Windows 10, there's a bajillion programs and shortcuts in that folder that I know do not start on Windows startup. Removing uTorrent shortcut at this path worked for me:

C:\Users\<My User Name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Answer (score 5):

#### Update:

> One commenter (СашаЧерных) suggested to create a new string: `uTorrent` in the registry at the following location:
>
> `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]`
>
> and set its value to `-`
>
> This solves the issue without needing to change any other windows settings.

#### It is most likely due to a setting in Windows 10

> There is a change with the Fall Creator’s Update where applications that have registered via RegisterApplicationRestart will re-open after a shutdown or reboot, read about it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerapplicationrestart?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
>
> You can mitigate this either by making sure that µTorrent has been shut down *before* you perform a restart. Or you can disable this functionality directly in settings:
>
> `Open Settings → Accounts → Sign-in options → Scroll down to Privacy`
>
> [image: a picture showing windows reopen settings under privacy]
>
> **Note:** There is unfortunately no way to disable this for individual applications as of this moment.

#### Other considerations

Ensure that `Start µTorrent when Windows Starts` is disabled, then exit the application completely:

[image: µtorrent setting window showing Windows Integration options]

During installation, there is also the option to enable/disable this functionality. And it is a possibility that "remnants" of these settings are located somewhere. But this is highly unlikely.

[image: µTorrent installation process, showing the automation settings]

In any case, I bet this has something to do with µTorrent running when you shut down your computer, and the Windows 10 Setting is enabled.

#### Keep in mind:

The startup applications have moved about a bit in Windows, and there are two distinct places you can manage this now. They show different results sometimes, and can have something to do with how certain applications register with either the old system or the new one.

## 1

Have a look in: Settings > Apps > Startup

[image: Windows new start up settings]

## 2

Have a look in Task Manager

[image: Task manager start up settings]

**But**, as a general recommendation, I would find another software instead of µTorrent, to use for your distro-sharing needs.

Comment: I will reward you the bounty, since the original Poster of the working answer (Саша Черных) does not create an answer. The solution:
The solution is to create a new `string` in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]` -> `uTorrent` with value `-`

Comment: I can add that to the answer as well :)

Comment: that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

So you'd disable it on your Windows Startup Programs manager.

`Start > Run > MSConfig`

Click the `Startup` tab, find your program, and uncheck the box.

You will get some popup warnings that these changes affect your computer and that is okay.

**FYI ABOUT uTORRENT** : Within the past few years, uTorrent changed their program so that it uses your computer to mine for bitcoins when you are idle (that is, it runs your computer hard so that they can make invisible internet money). I believe this information is not very visible when you are using or installing uTorrent. If your computer is frail and on its last legs, you want to beware of this.

**SECOND FYI ABOUT uTORRENT** : With peer-to-peer file sharing programs like uTorrent you need to beware that your computer is sharing files across the internet that may very well be illegally pirated. Even if you are not at your computer, do not ever see it, know of it, nor use it, your ISP does and they CAN decide that this alone constitutes pirating (certain files are specifically flagged and monitored across the internet). For many ISPs, they will simply shut off your internet and getting it turned back on is excruciatingly difficult.

Comment: Doesn't show up there either

Comment: @IgorPavkovic Well that's creepy. If it were me I'd uninstall it completely and try to install it again hoping that it was a bad installation last time

Answer (score 1):

From the `Run` prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), enter `shell:startup`, and `shell:common startup` and make sure no shortcuts to uTorrent exist in these folders.

Next, go to `Task Manager > Startup`, and disable uTorrent.

Lastly, open `Task Scheduler` and make sure that none of the enabled tasks run uTorrent.

Also: consider using [Deluge](https://www.deluge-torrent.org) as an alternative to uTorrent - works much better in my experience, is free (both as in free beer and free press), and has no ads.

Answer (score 0):

I have uTorrent 3.2 from BTGuard. In my startup list, it shows up as settings.exe, a blank publisher, and a torch icon.  Right click on that entry and verify that Properties shows a Location such as C:\BTGUARD.  Disable it.

uTorrent's install of 3.5.3 puts the expected Name and Publisher in the startup list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

C:\users(username)\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\startmenu\programs\start-up

Here you will find a uTorrent shortcut which links it to the uTorrent.exe file. Simply delete it. Reboot your system and it should start without uTorrent starting as well.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

After shutting down utorrent wait 5 seconds to shut down Windows.
That did it for me.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. The OP is talking about uTorrent starting with windows. If somehow it is still your answer, please try to back it up with a working example or something like that.

Comment: Windows will automatically reopen on start up the programs that where left open when shutting down.  If you close Utorrent and immediatly shut down the computer Windows had no time to completly shut down Utorrent therefore it will open it on start up.  Try it.  Works for me anyway.

Answer (score -1):

When you shut down utorrent immidiatly check the taskmanager and you will see that utorrent takes about 15 seconds to terminate. If you still dont beleive in my solution then endure.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question, which was about uTorrent starting when the computer starts, not about how to shut it down. Please read questions carefully to maximize the chance of understanding them fully and accurately before you attempt to answer.